# angular8 event binding syatax with () is not working in mobile browser

Tags: angular, angular8

I am practicing angular8.
The event binding syntax (click) is not triggering in mobile browser but the evet "onclick" is working fine

```
onclick="window.alert('product is shared')"
```

This is working fine in mobile chrome but

```
(click)="window.alert('product is shared')"
```

This is not working in mobile chrome. my chrome version is latest

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to move your function call in your component/typescript file ?

**Template**

```
(click)="onClick()"
```

#### Component

```
onClick() {
   window.alert('product is shared')
}
```